# Getting the whole record information with AWK

Tags: awk

I have an SDF file which looks like this:

```
$$$$
Mrv0541 02231217452D
 7 6 0 0 0 0 999 V2000
 1.2375 2.1434 0.0000 C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0.8250 1.4289 0.0000 C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1.2375 0.7145 0.0000 C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 2.0625 0.7145 0.0000 O 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0.8250 0.0000 0.0000 C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1.2375 -0.7145 0.0000 O 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 O 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
 2 3 1 0 0 0 0
 3 4 2 0 0 0 0
 3 5 1 0 0 0 0
 5 6 1 0 0 0 0
 5 7 2 0 0 0 0
M END
> <DATABASE_ID>
HMDB0000005
> <DATABASE_NAME>
hmdb
> <SMILES>
CCC(=O)C(O)=O
> <INCHI_IDENTIFIER>
InChI=1S/C4H6O3/c1-2-3(5)4(6)7/h2H2,1H3,(H,6,7)
$$$$
```

I want to print the information of the whole record that fills the condition of the field <DATABSE_ID> is equal to `HMDB0000005`. The separator is "$$$$" for each record.
What I've tried so far is:

```
awk -v RS="[$]{4}\n" 'NF'  '{if $1 == "HMDB0000005"}' file.sdf
```

But it's giving me an error which I believe is because there's something wrong in my command. Can you tell me what how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, if this is what you are looking for, written and tested with GNU `awk`. This will look for records from `$$$$` to next `$$$$` and will checks if that record has value of `HMDB0000005` it will print that record then.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[$]{4}\n' '/HMDB0000005\n/' Input_file
```

OR more robust(compare to above IMHO)

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[$]{4}\n' '/\n> <DATABASE_ID>\nHMDB0000005\n/' Input_file
```